# avoid crossdomain OPTIONS requests

Tags: apache, cross-domain

i've a project with frontend code and api code like project.com for frontend and api.project.com for api.

Because i've configured apache to accept cross domain request, browser accept to call different url but it also call api with OPTION request before each GET request.

how can i avoid OPTION requests?

I've only added below parameter for cross domain configuration;

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
```

Answer (score 2):

The custom Content-Type (application/json) is in fact triggering the preflight. According to the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), any Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain triggers the preflight.

Once the browser receives those headers, it will make the actual request. You can learn more about CORS preflight requests here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest will only send a [preflight options request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for a GET request if you set custom request headers. Stop trying to set custom request headers.

Comment: i have to set a couple of custom headers and still want to avoid from OPTIONS call, is it possible?

Comment: No. It isn't possible.

Comment: I've removed extra request headers but still it sends OPTIONS request. Any advise?

Comment: You shouldn't get the problem you describe now. You would need to provide more code to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you - but you could forbid OPTION requests in the apache config.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit

```
<Location /your/context>

  <Limit OPTIONS>
    Allow from x.y.z
    Deny from all
  </Limit> 

...
</...>
```